# Get email upon every "firebase deploy"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'd like to get an email upon every `firebase deploy`.

Reason: security - I want to know if someone hacks into my account and deploys an alternative firebase backend.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This feature doesn't exist.  You could file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: Thanks, I've just did.

Answer (score 0):

You can ahceive what you are after using Firebase Cloud Functions. Here an article, [Email via Firebase Firestore Cloud Function Triggers](https://hightechtele.com/articles/firestore-trigger-email) showing the exact script to email on one of these events that you can use/adapt to your specific needs/project.

For Firestore:

> #### [Trigger a Cloud Firestore function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)
>
> The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK exports a functions.firestore
>   object that allows you to create handlers tied to specific events.
>
> Cloud Firestore supports create, update, delete, and write events:
>
> Event Type    Trigger
>
> `.onCreate`   Triggered when a document is written to for the first time.
>
> `.onUpdate`   Triggered when a document already exists and has any value
>   changed.
>   `.onDelete` Triggered when a document with data is deleted.
>
> `.onWrite`    Triggered when .onCreate, .onUpdate or .onDelete is
>   triggered.

Comment: What trigger should I use to get emails for "firebase deploy"?

Comment: "firebase deploy" does several things - it deploys functions, hosting, database rules, etc. If your requirement is to watch events on your database, that can be achieved.

Comment: My requirement is to watch 'firebase deploy' itself, so that I know if someone tempers my backend functions (or even deletes them all).